# Is it possible to globally bind to a change event?

Tags: vue.js

I would like to trigger a method everytime the user switches to another field in a form. This does the job:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    theContent1: "",
    theContent2: ""
  },
  methods: {
    changeFun() {
      console.log('change')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.6/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <form>
    <input v-model="theContent1" @change="changeFun()">
    <input v-model="theContent2" @change="changeFun()">
  </form>
</div>
```

It is however repetitive when there are many fields. **Is there a way to globally bind to a method for any change?**

Note: I do not want to set a `watch` on the content of `data` - I need the method to be trigerred when the *edited element* changes, not when its *content* does. A practical example would be a submit once a field is completed and the user leaves it (but wihout submitting at each change of the value of the field while it is edited).

Comment: I don't understand at all the last sentence. You have lots of input events you can listen for: onkeypress, onchange, onblur, onfocus. The point is, you don't need to listen *on the element* that generates the event. You can listen at any level of the tree.

Comment: @bbsimonbb: I added a practical example, hope that it clarifies what I meant.

Comment: we use onblur for that. onchange works ok for text inputs, but fires all the time for dates, for example.

Comment: @bbsimonbb: oh, thanks for the information! That would match even closer to my usecase (where there will be date pickers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put your event listener at the root of your div. [All Dom events traverse the Dom down from the root, to the element that generated the event, then back up again !](https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/) You can listen for them at any level. Use `event.target` and `event.currentTarget` to find out what generated the event and what captured it.

Note that, for this reason, it's super agressive to stop the propagation of an event. All kinds of things above your element might have an interest in the events it generates.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    theContent1: "",
    theContent2: ""
  },
  methods: {
    changeFun(event) {
      console.log('change from '+event.target.id)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.6/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root" @change="changeFun">
  <form>
    <input id="one" v-model="theContent1">
    <input id="two" v-model="theContent2">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - this is exactly what I ws looking for. I took the liberty to amend your answer to add an example for the use of `event.target`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use watchers:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    theContent1: "",
    theContent2: ""
  },
  watch: {
    theContent1(newVal) {
      console.log('change from theContent1: ', newVal)
    },
    ...
  }
})
```

With this you'll have to set watchers for each too...

Comment: Thank you - but I explicitely stated in the "Note" of my question that I did not want to `watch` for changes in the content of a field (=the value of the bound `data` variable)